# Workaround for Internet Explorers java script block as control in WPF

Tags: javascript, wpf, security, internet-explorer, controls

For my project I need to show a html file which uses JavaScript to render LaTeX code. This works fine, but everytime I open this file in the browser for the first time, the yellow band pops up that active code won't be executed until the user accepts so. This is annoying in this case, although I understand the purpose, however I want to mark my code as trusted! Do you have any idea how to "hack" the control to achieve the behavior I want? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ist really stupid as the security policy is badly implemented by Microsoft. Just add  the comment`<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->\r\n` before everything else and the IE will recognize your local file as accessed from the internet and will then execute JavaScript code as wanted. But this is a better solution than hacking the registry...